# $T_1$- ness of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Basis of odd even topology like $\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},.....\}$.
I think $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ are different open set here.
Then why odd even topology is not $T_1$?
please explain

Comment: What is the underlying space, $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: N ,set of all natural numbers

Comment: The definition is [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Odd-Even_Topology) which is different.

Comment: And agrees with [this one](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces/S000005) from Counterexamples in Topology

Comment: hmm it is a easy one

Comment: sorry to ask...

Answer (score 0):

Its not even $T_0$: every open set that contains $0$ also contains $1$ and vice versa. Likewise for all pairs $2k-1,2k$